# [ExpectedException(typeof(AnExceptionBaseException))]

Tags: c#, mstest

I wrote a unit test in such a way that it *should* throw `AnException` or `AnotherException`, both deriving from `AnExceptionBaseException`. I then proceeded to add an `ExpectedExceptionAttribute` for the base exception, only to find that my test will still be marked as failed.

> Test Name:    Call_Should_Throw_If_Device_Is_Not_Ready Test
>
> ...
>
> Result Message:   Test method
>   DiskManagementTests.DiskFreeSpaceTests.Call_Should_Throw_If_Device_Is_Not_Ready
>   threw exception System.IO.FileNotFoundException, but exception
>   System.IO.IOException was expected. Exception message:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The device is not ready. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80070015)

This seems like a reasonable design decision because, in this particular case, the exception is generated from an HRESULT return code. That makes it nearly impossible to determine which exception will be thrown. At least not without copying the code logic from the unit that my test is supposed to ...test.

My code (I believe this can throw either `FileNotFound` or `DirectoryNotFound`):

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(IOException))]
public void Call_Should_Throw_If_Device_Is_Not_Ready()
{
    foreach (DriveInfo drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives().Where(drive => !drive.IsReady))
    {
        DiskFreeSpace diskFreeSpace = DiskManagement.GetDiskFreeSpace(drive.RootDirectory.FullName);
        Assert.Fail("API call did not fail even though the drive reports that it is not ready.");
    }
    Assert.Inconclusive("All drives were ready. Try testing with an empty disc drive.");
}
```

Do I need to reconsider the way I write unit tests?

**EDIT**

This scenario is supported after all. All it really took was setting `AllowDerivedTypes` to true.

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(IOException), AllowDerivedTypes = true)]
public void Call_Should_Throw_If_Device_Is_Not_Ready()
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. The `ExpectedException` attribute is used for tests that will ALWAYS throw the expected exception. That's what it is testing. Will your test always throw an `IOException`?? If the Device is ready I guess not.

Comment: That's why it skips drives that are ready. If all drives are ready, the assertion is inconclusive. If the method call did not throw, the assertion fails.

Comment: Under all other circumstances, the call (should) throw an exception that extends `IOException`. However it's really difficult to determine which one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own `ExpectedException` attribute that will check if the thrown exception inherites  the Exception defined in the attribute.

```
public sealed class MyExpectedException : ExpectedExceptionBaseAttribute
{
    private Type _expectedExceptionBaseType;

    public MyExpectedException(Type expectedExceptionType)
    {
        _expectedExceptionBaseType = expectedExceptionType;
    }

    protected override void Verify(Exception exception)
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull(exception);
        Assert.IsTrue(exception.GetType().IsInstanceOfType(typeof(_expectedExceptionBaseType)) || 
                      exception.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(_expectedExceptionBaseType)));
    }
}
```

and change the attribute to your test:

```
[MyExpectedException(typeof(IOException))]
```

Comment: Wow. It's that simple.

Comment: Small gotcha: `IsSubclassOf()` returns false when the expected base type and the actual type are the same.

Comment: I just noticed that the framework's attribute comes with an `AllowDerivedTypes` property. I don't know how I missed that before. I added an example to my original post.